# MongoDB not inserting discord data

Tags: python, database, mongodb, discord.py

I have a MongoDB database for my my Discord bot, which stores user IDs, XP and level, and it was working fine up until I wanted to log avatar URLs in the database too.

When I added a column for the avatar URL, it just did nothing, and wouldn't insert any new data.

This is the code I have:

```
post = {
    "UserID": member.id,
    "AvatarURL": member.avatar_url,
    "Username": member.display_name,
    "XP": 0,
    "Level": 0,
    "XPLock": datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
}
collection.insert_one(post)
```

Could there be a limit for how much data a single cell can hold?

Comment: `print(collection.insert_one(post))` should print out the id if it was successful, what does that give you?

Comment: What's the error? There is a document limit of 16 MB, nothing on a certain field within it (none that I know of).

Comment: @TenaciousB **EDIT**: It gives me nothing actually, I had an extra print statement in there which I forgot about

Comment: @GandalftheWhite It doesn't give any error, it just does nothing and inserts no data.

Comment: sorry, I meant `collection.insert_one(post).inserted_id`

Comment: @TenaciousB It just prints nothing

Comment: are you sure that piece of code is being triggered?

Comment: Yes, I put extra print statements around everything, and it never makes it past ```collection.insert_one(post)```

Comment: @TenaciousB Anything else I can do to try fix it?

Comment: is you rmongodb connection string correct?

Comment: have your tried something like this : variable = insert operation. How do you check what the revert from MongoDB is? Not aware about this module being used. There has to be an error or something.

Comment: well the code isn't even completing the insert according to his earlier comments. I think the issue is in the actual inserting. Since the discord.py code is probably async, it appears as if the operation returned nothing when it hasn't finished yet.

Comment: There’s no error, which I find weird. And it works perfectly fine when I remove the avatar url part, so it could be an async issue but I’m not sure.